# Testing Invertibility of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In Paul Zeitz's the Art and Craft of Problem Solving, he says on page 34 that one way to show that a matrix $\mathbf{C}$ is invertible is by showing that $\mathbf{C} b_i \neq 0$ for each basis vector $b_i$. However, this can't be true -- consider the example
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Am I just tripping and misinterpreting what he wrote?

Comment: A square matrix is invertible iff its determinant is nonzero.

Comment: Presumably he means that you have to check it for every member of **every** basis. Not just one basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better way of putting this statement is the equation $Ax=0$ has only one solution , x=0 if A is invertible, so any basis for $R^n$ would not include that zero vector (as it contradicts linear independence) so for any basis of $R^n$ , the basis vectors can't be left multiplied to give 0. (Whereas in your counterexample I can take $<1,-1>$, $<0,1>$ as a basis for $R^2$ and we get a left multiplication to give zero.)